# Como puedo exportar datos de una tabla separados por ; en vez de por ,

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Hola estoy intentando exportar una tabla pero al exportarla automáticamente como terminador de campo ',' y lo que me gustaría con seguir es que el separador de campo sea ';'. Para ello estoy utilizando un procedimiento almacenado.

[image: Código Utilizado]

Lo que consigo es:

Part_Number,Tool_Number,...

1,1,...

Y lo que quiero conseguir es:

Part_Number;Tool_Number;...

1;1;...

Muchas Gracias.
Un Saludo Carlos.

Comment: Buenas @CarlosZuazu, debes poner el código escrito en la pregunta y no en una foto, de esta manera lo podremos copiar y pegar para hacer nosotros mismos las pruebas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *En tus futuras preguntas sería bueno que añades la consulta que realices y no poner una imagen.*

---

Al momento de exportar y que la separación de datos, solo sería necesario modificar `-t,` por `-t;`. Por ejemplo:

```
... -U sa -P comanai -c -t; -S DESKTOP-...
```

Argumento:

> **-t** field_term
>
> Especifica el terminador del campo. El valor predeterminado es \t (carácter de tabulación).

---

**Referencia:**

- [bcp (utilidad)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/tools/bcp-utility#t)